# setCurrentId(prop) is not a function in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, react-props

I am getting this error message in console (Uncaught TypeError: setCurrentId is not a function
at onClick (Post.js:19:1) )

I don't know how to handle this error
This is Child Component Post.js

```
import { Button, Card,CardActions,CardContent,CardMedia,Typography } from '@material-ui/core';
import React from 'react';
import useStyles from "./styles";
import MoreHorizIcon from '@mui/icons-material/MoreHoriz';
import DeleteIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Delete';
import ThumbUpAltIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ThumbUpAlt';
import moment from 'moment';
const Post= ({post , setCurrentId})=>{
    const classes = useStyles();
    return(
    <Card className={classes.card}>

<CardMedia className={classes.media} image={post.selectedFile} title={post.title}/>
    <div className={classes.overlay}>
            <Typography variant='h6'>{post.creator}</Typography>
            <Typography variant='body2'>{moment(post.createdAt).fromNow()}</Typography>
    </div>
        <div className={classes.overlay2}>
        <Button style={{ color: 'white' }} size="small" onClick={() => setCurrentId(post._id)}><MoreHorizIcon fontSize="default" /></Button>
        </div>
        <div className={classes.details}>
            <Typography variant='body2' color='textSecondary'>{post.tags.map((tag)=>`#${tag} `)}</Typography>
        </div>
        <CardContent>
        <Typography className={classes.title} variant='h5' gutterBottom>{post.message}</Typography>
        </CardContent>
        <CardActions className={classes.cardActions}>
            <Button size = 'small' color='primary' onClick={()=>{}}>
                <ThumbUpAltIcon fontSize='small'/>
                    Like
                    {post.likeCount}
            </Button>
            <Button size = 'small' color='primary' onClick={()=>{}}>
                <DeleteIcon fontSize='small'/>
                    Delete  
            </Button>
        </CardActions>
        
    </Card>

    )
}
export default Post;
```

This is parent Component

```
import React from 'react';
import { Grid, CircularProgress } from '@material-ui/core';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

import Post from './Post/Post';
import useStyles from './styles';

const Posts = ({ setCurrentId }) => {
  const posts = useSelector((state) => state.posts);
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    !posts.length ? <CircularProgress /> : (
      <Grid className={classes.container} container alignItems="stretch" spacing={3}>
        {posts.map((post) => (
          <Grid key={post._id} item xs={12} sm={6} md={6}>
            <Post post={post} setCurrentId={setCurrentId} />
          </Grid>
        ))}
      </Grid>
    )
  );
};
```

This is main file App.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Container, AppBar, Typography, Grow, Grid } from '@material-ui/core';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

import Posts from './components/Posts/Posts';
import Form from './components/Form/Form';
import { getPosts } from './actions/posts';
import useStyles from './styles';
import memories from './images/memories.png';

const App = () => {
  const [currentId, setCurrentId] = useState(0);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const classes = useStyles();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getPosts());
  }, [currentId, dispatch]);

  return (
    <Container maxWidth="lg">
      <AppBar className={classes.appBar} position="static" color="inherit">
        <Typography className={classes.heading} variant="h2" align="center">Memories</Typography>
        <img className={classes.image} src={memories} alt="icon" height="60" />
      </AppBar>
      <Grow in>
        <Container>
          <Grid container justify="space-between" alignItems="stretch" spacing={3}>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={7}>
              <Posts setCurrentId={setCurrentId} />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={4}>
              <Form currentId={currentId} setCurrentId={setCurrentId} />
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Container>
      </Grow>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I am trying to debug my react code and expecting something that I missed

Comment: Are you sure that the only place you use `<Post>` is in `<Posts>` component?

Comment: Try to debug in Posts component,  make sure that function is correctly pass from App,  debug step by step.